# FATAL: psql connection error on ec2 instace

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, psql

I've my application hosted on EC2/EBS and I can't access it using the IP address as it throws a `403 Forbidden Error`. I believe the issue seems to be my psql db as the psql logs have the following error:

[image]

I'm not sure what to do to fix this, especially since it's on the EC2

Answer (score 1):

Please check password in  pg_hba.conf as it is password authentication failed. It means you are providing wrong password somehow.